# Can I remove an HDD from a laptop and place it in another one without any issues?

Tags: hard-drive, drivers

I'm currently using a Fujitsu Amilo Pi 3660 ( It's equipped with an Nvidia Geforce GT 240M graphic card, Intel Core 2 Duo T6600 processor and a 4GB RAM ) and I'm planning on buying an HP G5 255 ( A6-7310/AMD Radeon R4 Graphics/4GB RAM/500GB HDD/No OS ). The amilo that I'm using has a 2.5inc HDD drive which has windows 10 and all my files and programs in it. Will I be able to remove the HDD from the amilo and place it in the HP G5 without any problems? Will I have to install certain drivers? What problems could I face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Depends**

I do this routinely at work, as sometimes the hardware dies, but the disk is fine, and just swapping the hardware leaving the software intact is usually the quickest operation, as time is usually an important factor.
In my case, the hardware is usually the same, or at least very similar. Network settings usually get dropped, as network settings are often tied to the MAC address of the NIC in question.

In other cases, some issues may arise in terms of drivers. If the hardware is very different, so will the drivers. If on windows, this can cause some issues. I remember Win2000 often getting BSOD if the hardware was replaced.

In other words: The more similar the hardware, the higher chance of success. In my experience, windows tends to be more cranky than other OSes when it comes to more radical changes.

Answer (score 1):

The worst thing which may happen is a blue screen while booting, which usually means that your prevoiusly installed system has no idea how to talk to the new system's hard disk controller because of missing drivers (or different bios settings - ACPI/non-ACPI). But if you switch the disk back your old system will still work.

In the most cases your new system will successfully boot from the old hard disk and try to reinstall all required drivers. You may have to reactivate some of your licenses which are nowadays mostly tied to hardware IDs.
In the most cases I would recommend a reinstall because you get rid of all the old stuff which is slowing your system down (which is getting worse after the move because you still have all the unneeded old drivers and registry settings from the old system)

But if you are in an emergency situation the hard disk swap is definitely an option.

Comment: The reason why I want to use my current HDD is because I don't want to pay in order to get a new copy of Win10.

Comment: If your Windows license came with the machine, it is probably OEM, and it is _bound to the machine_ (CPU), not the hard disk. Even if you get it to run in a new machine, you’d be violating the license terms.

Comment: This^^^ with only a tiny correction: It is bound to the firmware (UEFI), not the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

On the new computer first disable UEFI (in the BIOS) or whatever it is called unless your existing computer has it.

Connect it to the new computer and see if you get an error.
If you do connect it back, and do the following

from an administrative command prompt.

**Note: Make sure no unattended.inf is present in the below folder.**

```
cd \windows\sytem32\sysprep
sysprep /oobe /generalize
```

**Note:  If you get an error message it will have to be resolved first.  As a general rule windows will complain about windows store apps and you will have to uninstall the ones it complains about before it will complete.**

Connect to your new computer, and wait probably about 10 minutes for to finish its job.

Install all the new drivers for the new hardware.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Windows needs specific drivers for running on specific devices.  So, I would always search for "drivers $newmodelname" and install them manually before attempting to do the physical HD move you mentioned.  However, some driver installers refuse to install if the relevant hardware is not detected, and some of those driver installers are absolutely required in order to make the machine usable.  It may not boot at all in the new PC.

Comment: So I can't download the new drivers through the new laptop (while using my HDD)? That's what I was planning on doing but it seems like it won't work.

Comment: The only thing you have to lose is time.  Plus all of your data, and a small chance of breaking either or both laptops.  You mentioned in another comment that you're doing this to avoid paying a Win10 license.  I might suggest that you are being penny-wise, but pound-foolish, that is, saving money in places where it's wasteful and harmful in the long run.  :) Install Ubuntu on the new laptop.  Whole new worlds of learning.